# Efficient way to determine media deletion via Instagram API

Tags: php, api, instagram

Currently I am calling Instagram API to get media with a certain #hastag.  To make this process as efficient as possible and reduce calls to the API, data is cached on the server.

The purpose of this is to display some of the posts randomly on a website, but to respect the users privacy and Instagram rules, we need to get rid of the cached posts if it has been removed from Instagram.

The way I'm retrieving the media right now is calling the recent media endpoint for this tag each time my subscription alerts my app that there are updates.

So basically I need an efficient way to know if a post has been removed from Instagram, so that I can immediately remove it from my cache.  I realize this can be done with a large number of calls to the API, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Did the answer work for you?  I'm curious about trying something similar.

Answer (score 2):

When you save any of the original image/video url's you could periodically check whether this image still exists. If not, it's probably safe to assume that the original post has been removed. 
This way multiple API calls, are replaced by even more datacalls, but it should be a lot faster and no limits are enforced.

Comment: You can probably use a HEAD request to the media urls to find out. I have not tested this works though.